# Can you remove a text line in PHP with OpenTBS if there is nothing merged

Tags: php, yii, docx, opentbs

I have been using OpenTBS for modifying DOCX files.  When I am merging my DB info with the DOCX file it always leave blank data for any info in my DB that is missing.

Here is an image of my 'source' document on the left and my merge on the right. [image: Merging document issue in OpenTBS]

How do I go about removing the extra line breaks?

Here is the code producing this merge if it assists you

```
    public function mergeFields($template_file, Array $user, Array $lead){
        require_once('components/tbs_class_php5.php');
        require_once('components/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');

        //Instantiate new class
        $tbs = new clsTinyButStrong;
        $tbs->NoErr = true;
        $tbs->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL,OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

        $tbs->LoadTemplate($template_file);
        $tbs->MergeBlock('l',$lead);
        $tbs->MergeBlock('u',$user);
        $mergeFile = dirname(Yii::app()->basePath).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'components/merge.docx';

        $tbs->Show(OPENTBS_FILE, $mergeFile);
        chmod($mergeFile,0755);
        return $mergeFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever field you think is not compulsory or can have a null value, include a magnet tag like following :

> [l.co;magnet=w:p]

Here *magnet* is a conditional which deletes the tag if the value is null or empty. It is having the value "w:p" because DOCX's XML file contains all the new values in a tag like :-

```
<w:p>...</w:p>
```

So it will delete the tag and whitespace will be removed.

Comment: `[l.co;magnet=tbs:p]` does the same but is smarter.

Comment: I didn't know that. I read the question and researched till I found the answer :P

Thanks!

Comment: **this** is going to be a life saver.  I am verifying this now.  @Skrol29 I love the extension but was unclear in the docs on what to do.  Glad you are around helping though!  You too Parry

Comment: @Skrol29 what does `tbs:p` do compared to `w:p`?

Comment: @CGSmith105 tbs:p is intelligent selector for magnet. It automatically detects which file type is being used as a magnet and selects the paragraph and remove it. See this link http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.html#blockalias

Comment: @Parry: this is correct. "tbs:p" is a block alias for a paragraph and it is available in any document type. While "w:p" works only with DOCX. But in DOCX `tbs:p` = `w:p`.

Comment: @Skrol29 I tried `tps:p` and `w:p` and only `w:p` worked for me.